# multiple build definitions using the same workspace/build

Tags: tfs, build

In `TFS 2010`, I am looking for a way to have multiple build definitions that all build in the same agent folder. The reason for this is that I am trying to implement Gated Checkin but do not want to have to build the entire branch every time so I have created multiple builds that only build a subset of the solutions/projects.

```
Example Branch:

MyBranch:

- Folder1
 * Solution1A
 * Solution1B
- Folder2
 * Solution2A
 * Solution2B
```

**Example Build Definitions:**

```
 - MyBranchBuild - builds all solutions in all folders
 - MyBranchFolder1Build - builds all solutions under Folder1
 - MyBranchFolder2Build - builds all solutions under Folder2
```

**Example Build Agents:**

```
 - GateAgent1
  * Builds in C:\GateAgent1\MyBranch
 - GateAgent2
  * Builds in C:\GateAgent2\MyBranch

Currently MyBranchBuild contains in the Workspace definition "Build Agent Folder":
 - $(BuildDir)\Folder1
 - $(BuildDir)\Folder2
```

`MyBranchFolder1Build` and `MyBranchFolder2Build` only contain workspace mappings for their intended folders.

GateAgent1 & 2 use variations on the below working directory:

```
C:\GateAgent1\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
```

My resulting builds are going to

```
- C:\GateAgent1\MyBranchBuild
 - C:\GateAgent1\MyBranchFolder1Build
 - C:\GateAgent1\MyBranchFolder2Build
```

Again, my goal is for all 3 to build under:

```
- C:\GateAgent1\MyBranch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

- Build Definition->Build Agent Folder = $(SourceDir)\MyBranch\Folder1
- Build Agent Properties->Working Directory = C:\GateAgent1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(BuildDefinitionPath) property, you can specify the hard-coded branch name in working directory under Agent properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should have mentioned the fact that I actually have multiple branches for which I want to set this up and use the build agents for building all of them.

So I will actually have:
C:\GateAgent1\MyBranch1
C:\GateAgent1\MyBranch2

Comment: Its not easy to get the branch because a single build definition can be configured to build different branches and also there is no default teambuild property for branch name. You should use BuildDefinitionName or some other property to create agent workspace folders.